# how to add a line after nth occurrence of a keyword from file 1 to file 2

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, sed

```
# Nexae Linux servers
##
subparent Nexas Nexae_NIX Linux
title Nexae Linux servers

group-eorted NFe zluetere
10.48.37.67 zintxzpanae01       # teetip NOzOLUMNe:info,trende
10.59.31.67 etrtxzpanae01       # teetip NOzOLUMNe:info,trende

group-sorted ZBTS

10.48.37.11 zinpl001z3a01       #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.12 zinpl001z3a02       #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.13 zinpl001z3a03       #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.14 zinpl001z3a04       #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.41 zinpl001z3b01       #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.42 zinpl001z3b02       #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.31 zinvl201a3001       #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.32 zinvl201a3002       #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.33 zinvl201a3003       #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.150 zinvl201a3004      #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.151 zinvl201a3005      #"TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.152    zinvl201a3006   # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.20 zinvl201a3007       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.39 zinvl201a3008       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.65 zinvl201a3009       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.66 zinvl201a3010       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.70 zinvl201a3011       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.158    zinvl201a3012   # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.48.37.34     zinvl201a3013   # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.11 etrpl001z1a01       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.12 etrpl001z1a02       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.13 etrpl001z1a03       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.14 etrpl001z1a04       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.31 etrvl201a1001       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.32 etrvl201a1002       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.33 etrvl201a1003       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.150    etrvl201a1004   # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.151    etrvl201a1005   # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.152    etrvl201a1006   # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.44 etrvl201a1008       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.47 etrvl201a1009       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.39 etrvl201a1010       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.65 etrvl201a1011       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.66 etrvl201a1012       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
10.59.31.70 etrvl201a1013       # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"
170.252.208.216 etrvl201a1007   # "TRENDe:*,netetat:netetat|netetat1|netetat2|netetat3"

#######################################################
##
```

Above is the example of `HO` file. I'm using below `sed` code to match the keyword `group-sorted NTTA` in file `ho` and then insert all the entries from file `t4` into `ho`.

```
sed -i.bak '/^group-sorted NTTA$/!b;N;N;r t4' ho
```

But the keyword `group-sorted NTTA` appears in file 15 times, so if I want to insert the entries after middle keyword. Can I do that with `sed`?

Comment: Thanks Inian for nice editing , now it looks like a question.

Comment: what is the content of `t4` file? Also, elaborate your *middle keyword* relatively to *15 times*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the contents of file t4 two lines after the `n`-th occurrence of `^group-sorted NTTA$` in file H0, try:

```
awk -v n=2 'FNR==NR{t=t"\n"$0;next} /^group-sorted NTTA$/ && n==++cnt {x=NR+3} NR==x{print substr(t,2)} 1' t4 H0
```

While there undoubtedly is a `sed` solution to this problem, `awk` is a more natural choice here because `awk` understands arithmetic.  This, for example, makes it easier to program `awk` to do something after the `n`-th occurrence of something where `n` is a variable.

#### How it works

- `-v n=2`

  This sets the value of `n`.
- `FNR==NR{t=t"\n"$0;next}`

  When reading the first-named file, `t4`, this saves its contents in variable `t`.
- `/^group-sorted NTTA$/ && n==++cnt {x=NR+3}`

  While reading the second-named file, `H0`, the number of occurrences of `^group-sorted NTTA$` is saved in variable `cnt`.  If `cnt` is equal to `n`, then we assign variable `x` to the value of the current line number, `NR`, plus 3.
- `NR==x{print substr(t,2)}`

  When we have reached line number `x`, we print the contents of variable `t`.  (The `substr` command removes a superfluous leading newline character.)
- `1`

  This is awk's shorthand for print-the-current-line.

#### Example

Consider these input files:

```
$ cat H0
blah, blah
group-sorted ZBTS

10.48.37.11 zinpl001z3a01 #"TRENDe
10.48.37.12 zinpl001z3a02 #"TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.11 etrpl001z1a01       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.12 etrpl001z1a02       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.13 etrpl001z1a03       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.14 etrpl001z1a04       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.31 etrvl201a1001       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.32 etrvl201a1002       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.33 etrvl201a1003       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.150    etrvl201a1004       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.151    etrvl201a1005       # "TRENDe
```

And:

```
$ cat t4
line 1 of t4
line 2 of t4
```

The output from our command is:

```
$ awk -v n=2 'FNR==NR{t=t"\n"$0;next} /^group-sorted NTTA$/ && n==++cnt {x=NR+3} NR==x{print substr(t,2)} 1' t4 H0
blah, blah
group-sorted ZBTS

10.48.37.11 zinpl001z3a01 #"TRENDe
10.48.37.12 zinpl001z3a02 #"TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.11 etrpl001z1a01       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.12 etrpl001z1a02       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.13 etrpl001z1a03       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.14 etrpl001z1a04       # "TRENDe
line 1 of t4
line 2 of t4
10.59.31.31 etrvl201a1001       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.32 etrvl201a1002       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.33 etrvl201a1003       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.150    etrvl201a1004       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.151    etrvl201a1005       # "TRENDe
```

Comment: Tht's really a nice explanation thanks, let me check this in my script..give me sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Input file1

```
cat H0

blah, blah
group-sorted ZBTS

10.48.37.11 zinpl001z3a01 #"TRENDe
10.48.37.12 zinpl001z3a02 #"TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.11 etrpl001z1a01       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.12 etrpl001z1a02       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.13 etrpl001z1a03       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.14 etrpl001z1a04       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.31 etrvl201a1001       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.32 etrvl201a1002       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.33 etrvl201a1003       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.150    etrvl201a1004       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.151    etrvl201a1005       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.33 etrvl201a1003       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.150    etrvl201a1004       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.151    etrvl201a1005       # "TRENDe
```

Input file2

```
cat t4

10
20
```

Command

```
 c=`sed -n -e '/group-sorted NTTA/{=;p;}' H0| sed "N;s/\n/ /g" | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n ''$y'p' | awk '{print 2 + $1}'`;sed ''$c'r t4' H0
```

Output

```
blah, blah
group-sorted ZBTS

10.48.37.11 zinpl001z3a01 #"TRENDe
10.48.37.12 zinpl001z3a02 #"TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.11 etrpl001z1a01       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.12 etrpl001z1a02       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.13 etrpl001z1a03       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.14 etrpl001z1a04       # "TRENDe
10
20
10.59.31.31 etrvl201a1001       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.32 etrvl201a1002       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.33 etrvl201a1003       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.150    etrvl201a1004       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.151    etrvl201a1005       # "TRENDe

group-sorted NTTA

10.59.31.33 etrvl201a1003       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.150    etrvl201a1004       # "TRENDe
10.59.31.151    etrvl201a1005       # "TRENDe
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i'll go with the awk one, it's working. Though it is editing the same file.